# Send email without using SMTP

Tags: email, iis, outlook, smtp

I would like to send an email without using an SMTP server. I have tried using CDO.Message to send email. It works fine in IIS5.0 but not with IIS6.0. Is there a way to save emails to a pickup directory that outlook will use to send through it's own processes or some other option than using an SMTP server? Our firewalls blcok port 25 fairly aggresively unless it is coming from outlook directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Outlook to send your message, you need to use the Outlook Object Model for that.

Comment: I don't want to open outlook as an application. I simply want to be able to send emails. My problem is, our firewalls tend to block port 25 and email sending unless outlook sends them. I'm looking for a way around this for our automated email reports.

Comment: If you are using the OUtlook Object Model, it does not mean Outlook window will become visible. You can also use Redemption (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) - it uses Extended MAPI without starting Outlook.