# Add an HTML link in the body of a MAILTO link

Tags: javascript, email, mailto

Is there any way to add a HTML link to the body of a `mailto` email?

I know this is possible with activeX but I can't use that (I need it to work in other browsers than IE)

Something like this:

```
 body=<a href='http:www.test.com'> link </a>
 window.location.href = "mailto:" + emailTo + "?subject=" + subject+ "&body=" + body;
```

Comment: Be careful - mailto links are no longer recommended for use in webpages due to vulnerability to email scamming

Comment: Is there an alternative?

Comment: Yup - a dedicated php based contact form that sends mail out from the server

Comment: Thank you but I'm using .NET and I don't need to send an email, just to open the email on the user's computer (Internal website)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

Place the full url in the body variable when a mailto link is created.

```html
<a href="emailadress?Subject=Test&body=go%20to%20this%20link%20for%20me:%20http://stackoverflow.com">mailto</a>
```

The URL needs to have a full path. All email clients should be able to make this into a link when a mailto link is clicked.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

**This Will Help You**

http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/email-form-mailto.html

[is there anyway to SEND eMails in intranet environment without using SMTP in C#.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236470/is-there-anyway-to-send-emails-in-intranet-environment-without-using-smtp-in-c)

Comment: Thank you, but I do not see how it can help me, I'm looking for a client side solution to add a HTML link to a body of an email without using activex.